# JavaScript click not working

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the menu the bar is supposed to show but it doesn't.
I think it has to do with the click event. I kept the original code that worked on the codeacademy website but I would love to tweak some of that code. The code came from code academy and I wanted to try it on my own computer. Is there anything I did wrong?

```js
var main = function() {
  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 200);
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);
  });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
body {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/* Initial menu */
.menu {
  background: #202024 url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/black-thread.png') repeat left top;
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

/* Basic styling */

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/bg.png'); 
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   
    <link href='stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet'>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="menu">
      
      <!-- Menu icon -->
      <div class="icon-close">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
      </div>

      <!-- Menu -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Main body -->
    <div class="jumbotron">

      <div class="icon-menu">
        
        Menu
      </div>
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet you shared does work. Your problem is likely due to how you're including the jquery library. The leading `//` tells the computer to load jquery using the same protocol as the current page. On your computer that protocol will be `file:///` which means the browser will try to load jquery from `file:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` which doesn't exist on your computer. Change it to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` and it will probably work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) im new to web scripting your answer was very clear.